# Remove a listener that gets bound dynamically to undetermined elements?

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events

I have the following code and I would need help to remove all my listeners, including the `func` listener which may be applied to multiple elements :

```
var associateListener = function(event)
{
    var element = event.srcElement||event.target;
    element.addEventListener("click", func, false);
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", func, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", func, false);    
};
var addListeners = function(win)
{
    win.document.addEventListener("click", associateListener, true);
    win.document.addEventListener("mousedown", associateListener, true);
    win.document.addEventListener("mouseup", associateListener, true);
};
var deleteListeners = function(win)
{
    ??
};
```

I tried to put :

```
win.document.removeEventListener("click", associateListener, true);
win.document.removeEventListener("mousedown", associateListener, true);
win.document.removeEventListener("mouseup", associateListener, true);
```

but it didn't remove the listeners associated to the elements.
I'd like to remove also these listeners.

Comment: You add all 3 listeners to the document and to some elements (based on the event). You need to know all these elements, so you can remove the listeners from them. You are not doing this, so the listeners are not removed...

Comment: Seems to work for me... http://jsfiddle.net/7jQJj/

Comment: @smerny your fiddle is not removing the listener

Comment: Check your console, on initial load if you click in the `result` section you'll see `associateListener` getting called. After clicking "Remove Listeners", you wont... this means it was removed.

Comment: It still prints "func" in the console, I guess this means it is still there

Comment: @BalintBako I tried to do this also : I created an array called elems and each time I enter in the associateListener function I push the current element. In my deleteListeners at the end I look throught the array and I remove the listener for each elem in elems. But it didn't work.

Comment: @smerny For me it doesn't work.

Comment: He is trying to remove the "func" listeners, the other is working as he did...

Comment: @user2302725, can you clarify what didn't work and what you expect to happen?

Comment: "but it didn't remove the listeners associated to the elements" what else is attached to the elements if not func?

Comment: @smerny Yes I am trying to remove the listener associated to the element. So I expect that the function "func" doesn't happen when I click on an element.

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said before, I tried to use an array but it didn't seem to work. I am thinking about an other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/7jQJj/3/

```
var elesBound = []
var func = function () {
    console.log("func from ele: "+this.tagName+"(id: "+this.id+")");
}
var associateListener = function (event) {
    console.log("associateListener");
    var element = event.srcElement || event.target;
    element.addEventListener("click", func, false);
    element.addEventListener("mousedown", func, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", func, false);
    elesBound.push(element);
};
var addListeners = function (win) {
    console.log("addListeners");
    win.document.addEventListener("click", associateListener, true);
    win.document.addEventListener("mousedown", associateListener, true);
    win.document.addEventListener("mouseup", associateListener, true);
};
var deleteListeners = function (win) {
    console.log("deleteListeners");
    win.document.removeEventListener("click", associateListener, true);
    win.document.removeEventListener("mousedown", associateListener, true);
    win.document.removeEventListener("mouseup", associateListener, true);
    for (var i = 0; i < elesBound.length; i++) {
        elesBound[i].removeEventListener("click", func, false);
        elesBound[i].removeEventListener("mousedown", func, false);
        elesBound[i].removeEventListener("mouseup", func, false);
    }
    elesBound = [];
};
document.getElementById("removeListeners").addEventListener("click", function () {
    deleteListeners(window);
});
addListeners(window);
```

Basically I kept a list that keeps track of which elements are bound to func, then unbind them all on deleteListeners.

Example of what you'll see in the console:

```
addListeners
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d2) 
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d2) 
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d2) 
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d1) 
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d1) 
associateListener 
func from ele: DIV(id: d1) 
associateListener 
func from ele: BUTTON(id: removeListeners) 
associateListener 
func from ele: BUTTON(id: removeListeners) 
associateListener 
deleteListeners
```

After this (when `deleteListeners` is called), you can click anywhere and your `associateListener` and `func` will not be called as all the event listeners will be removed.

Comment: That's what I did already. And it didn't work. The "func" function still happens.

Comment: It's working. I'll include an example of the console log. If you are getting different results, let me know what you were doing. I clicked to apply the func listener to both divs and the body as well, then clicked to delete listeners and tried clicking again in the same areas and did not see func get called.

Comment: I don't understand how it can work for you and not for me. I have exactly the same code, but my "func" function is always called when I click. If you're sure it works, I'll think about all that later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try it out in the jsfiddle I provided above. I don't see a reason that this would not work in another context as long as `associateListener` is called to create the binds and `deleteListeners` is called to remove them and you don't have any conflicts with the var you are using to store an array of bound elements.

Comment: Ok that worked, I had a syntax error somewhere and I didn't see it. Thank you :)